# usb has become read only

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I have a usb which I used to burn an iso file using dd. I now want to use it for other things so I used gparted and made a fat32 partition marked `/dev/sdb1` 7.35GiB which has a used space of 14.70MiB.

This looks normal enough and mount gives me:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/ilan/A6F5-30A8 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Even the permissions on Properties give Me access of Create and delete files. However when I try to do a copy-paste of any file it tells me:

```
The destination is read-only
```

In the mount I see `errors=remount-ro`, but there are no errors that I am aware of.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems and found that zeroing out the live usb with dd before reformatting prevents such issues:

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd[x]`

where `x` should be replaced by the letter of the usb device (e.g. `sdb`)